# Rdlc report inside usercontrol in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I have a rdlc report in a usercontrol, i need to load this usercontrol on button click from a page, But when i load the usercontrol on button click the reportviewer becomes null. But if i am loading usercontrol on the page without the button click its working fine.

PageButton Click event

```
protected void bGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            UsrReport Usr = new UsrReport();
            Usr.LoadControl("~/UsrReport.ascx");
            Usr.ID = "rptdetails";
            PnlReport.Controls.Add(Usr);
        }
```

UserControl.ascx

```
  <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptViewer" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="600px" 
    Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" 
    WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Usercontrol PageLoad

```
 if (rptViewer != null)
    {
        rptViewer.Visible = true;
        rptViewer.Reset();

        rptViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/rptLog.rdlc");
        var ReportData = DataConnection.GetDatalist("");
        ReportDataSource reportDSDetail = new ReportDataSource("DataList", 
ReportData);
        rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDSDetail);

    }
```

Comment: Can we see your ASPX, ASCX and relevant code!?

Comment: i have add the page button click event, in user control i am loading the report in page load.

Comment: Can we see this code too!?

Comment: i have updated all the codes, while in button click i'm creating a new object of the usercontrol to load. i think its where there reportviewer gets null. is the way i'm using correct..?